# :last-child of Elements with Class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering why I can not select the last child of elements with a specific class. It only works when ALL elements have the same class but as soon the last element has no class, it is not working.

Anything I miss here?

```css
.headerWithIcons div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headerIcons:last-child {
  opacity: .5;
}

.headerIconsDIV:last-child {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWithIcons">

  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>

  <!-- Only working when this div has the same class like the  elements above -->
  
  <div class="">Test</div>

</div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because :last-child does just that, selects the last child, not the last child with a specific class. Adding a class to the mix makes it act like a filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is no such selector that can select the last of a class, when there are other elements of the same type after it that have a different or no class. You can only get last of element type (`:last-of-type`) and last element (`:last-child`) and a specific element count (`:nth-child()`). However you are able to count backwards with `:nth-last-of-type(2)`. This would select the second to last element.

```css
.headerWithIcons div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headerIcons:last-child {
  opacity: .5;
}

.headerIconsDIV:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWithIcons">

  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>

  <!-- Only working when this div has the same class like the  elements above -->
  
  <div class="">Test</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Strange that it does not exist in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Just a keep a space between the class name and the colon. It will work. I edited your code and it works as the way you wanted

```css
.headerWithIcons div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headerWithIcons :last-child{
  opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerWithIcons">

  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>
  <div class="headerIconsDIV">Test</div>

  <!-- Only working when this div has the same class like the  elements above -->
  
  <div class="LastElement">Test</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure about what you want to do but if you want to associate something different to the last child div of your div 'headerWithIcons':

```
.headerWithIcons div:last-child {
  /** your styles for your last div */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Lastchild applies to the child elements, not the parent - and as such, the children have to be all the same type (not necessaritly the same class).

To grab the last child based on classname, you would use:

```
.headerIcons:last-child
```

To grab the last child without a class name, you would use:

```
.headerWithIcons div:last-child
```

Comment: That's what I did in my example. It seems only to work if all children have the same class.

Comment: You can either avoid giving them classnames and just target the <div>, or, if they are all different class names, use .headerWithIcons div:last-of-type instead. This wont care what the classnames are used.